# Different No. at risk in unweighted and weighted Kaplan-Meier curves

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I do not understand why the number of people at risk after weighting is different between the unweighted Kaplan-Meier curve and the weighted one. In the weighted Cox model, the number n is then correct again.

Data:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(cobalt)


set.seed(123)
options(scipen=999)
lalonde <- cbind(lalonde,
                   event = sample(c(0,1), size=614, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.84,0.16)),
                   time = runif(614, min=10, max=365))
```

I tried:

```
formula <- treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75 + re78

#PS
lalonde$pscore <- glm(formula, data = lalonde,
                                family = binomial(link = "logit"))$fitted.values

# Calculate MATCHING WEIGHTS
lalonde$weight <- ifelse(lalonde$treat == 1,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / lalonde$pscore,
                     pmin(lalonde$pscore, 1 - lalonde$pscore) / (1 - lalonde$pscore))

#####################################

#Fit model 
surv_object <- Surv(time = lalonde$time, event = lalonde$event)
fit1 <- survfit(surv_object ~ treat, data = lalonde, robust = TRUE, weights = lalonde$weight)

# Kaplan-Meier
KM <- ggsurvplot(
  fit1, 
  data = lalonde, 
  risk.table = TRUE, 
  legend.labs = c("Treat 0", "Treat 1"), 
  censor = FALSE
)
```

Here the Number at risk decreases to: Treat 0: 109 and Treat 1: 110.

In the original data without weighting: Treat 0: 429 and Treat 1: 185.

Now the Cox model:

```
#Weighted Cox model
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ treat, data=lalonde, weights = lalonde$weight, robust = TRUE)
cox
```

Here n = 614 as in original data.

Why is that?
Or did I miss something?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the number at risk is created by the sum of the weights:

`treated1 <- sum(lalonde$weight[lalonde$treat == 1])`
is 110

and

`treated0 <- sum(lalonde$weight[lalonde$treat == 0])`
is 109